# How to create a function to accept a parameter and increment it when called?

Tags: javascript, function

I have created a function that accepts a variable as its parameter to increment and other to display it.

However, it only increments the passed parameter by 1.

```
var p1_score = 0;

function updateScores(playerDisplay, scoreFor){
    if (!gameOver) {
        scoreFor++;
        playerDisplay.textContent = scoreFor;
    }if (scoreFor === winningScore){
        playerDisplay.classList.add("winner");
        gameOver = true;
    }
```

Here is when I call it:

```
p1_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    updateScores(p1_display, p1_score);
});
```

So when the button is clicked it does not increment p1_score more than 1.

Comment: The function increments the **copy** of the value it receives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should receive it back. Something like

```
function updateScores(playerDisplay, scoreFor){
    if (!gameOver) {
        scoreFor++;
        playerDisplay.textContent = scoreFor;
    }if (scoreFor === winningScore){
        playerDisplay.classList.add("winner");
        gameOver = true;
    }
    return  scoreFor;
}
```

And then

```
p1_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    p1_score = updateScores(p1_display, p1_score);
});
```

Or another solution is , simply declare it global.

```
   var scoreFor =0;
   function updateScores(playerDisplay, scoreFor){
        if (!gameOver) {
            scoreFor++;
            playerDisplay.textContent = scoreFor;
        }if (scoreFor === winningScore){
            playerDisplay.classList.add("winner");
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }

 p1_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        updateScores(p1_display);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh, was missing the return statement. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object, because with the object, you hand over the object reference and not a [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) value, which does not change the outer variable.

```
function updateScores(playerDisplay, scoreFor) {
    if (!gameOver) {
        scoreFor.value++;
        playerDisplay.textContent = scoreFor.value;
    } else if (scoreFor.value === winningScore) { // assuming an else if
        playerDisplay.classList.add("winner");
        gameOver = true;
    }
}

var p1_score = { value: 0 }; // object with value

p1_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    updateScores(p1_display, p1_score);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`p1_score` and `scoreFor` are two different variables. When you call the function, the first passes its value to the one inside the function. Since the value is a number (which is a **primitive value**), the number is copied rather than passed using a reference. So incrementing `scoreFor` will not affect `p1_score`.

This is possible in some other languages such as C++ for example, where there is pointers and pass-by-reference.

Change the function to something like this:

```
function updateScores(playerDisplay, scoreFor){
    // ...
    return scoreFor;    // return scoreFor after it's been altered
}
```

and then use the function like this:

```
p1_score = updateScores(p1_display, p1_score);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare scoreFor outside the function, I mean declare like a global variable and replace this: `scoreFor++;` with this: `scoreFor = scoreFor + 1`